# Welches Wort würde ein deutsches Kind für die Farbe in diesem rosigen Bild verwenden?

Tags: translation, noun

### Als Beispiel, die meisten deutschen Kinder würden eher das Wort „blau“ verwenden als das Wort „aquamarin“

[image: PICTURE OF FUSIA, ABER KINDER VERWENDEN DAS WORT "FUCHSIA" NICHT]

## Welches Wort würde ein deutsches Kind für die Farbe in diesem rosigen Bild verwenden?

Welches Substantiv o. Farbe? Es ist kein Adjektiv gefragt.

Die Motivation ist das Schreiben eines Compilers zum Transportieren/Portieren von Deutsch [**LaTeX**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) und [**MathJax**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) in amerikanisches Englisch [**LaTeX**](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)

| Englisch | Deutch |
| --- | --- |
| `$\color{aqua}{Filipino}$` | `$\farbe{aqua}{Philippinisch}$` |
| `$\color{black}{French}$` | `$\farbe{schwarz}{Französisch}$` |
| `$\color{blue}{Hangul}$` | `$\farbe{blau}{Koreanisch}$` |

Comment: Das Pink. Das Rosa.

Comment: ***die Farbe** in diesem rosigen Bild* – Das Bild enthält mehrere Farben. Um welche geht es? Das deutsche Kind, das ich spontan zur Hand hatte, hat *rosa, pink, rot, braun,* und *violett* geantwortet. Außerdem ist Farbkategorisierung vom Bildschirm und Kontext abhängig, siehe z. B. [The dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress) oder [die blauen Erdbeeren](https://www.sciencealert.com/in-spite-of-what-your-eyes-tell-you-these-strawberries-aren-t-red).

Comment: Die meisten Erwachsenen würden auch eher blau als aquamarin verwenden.

Comment: Warum ist nur die Wortwahl von Kindern aus Deutschland von Interesse? Wenn man sich für Begriffe aus der englischen Sprache interessiert, fragt man dann auch nur Kinder aus England? Warum werden bei solchen Fragestellungen deutsche Muttersprachler, die keine Deutschen sind, immer diskriminiert?

Comment: Die Motivation vestehe ich ehrlich gesagt immer noch nicht, auch wenn die schon in einer früheren Frage genannt wurde. Wenn ich einem Computer eine gewollte Farbe beschreiben will, will ich ja normalerweise die genauste Bezeichnung benutzen, die ich finden kann (hellrosa, altrosa, magenta. neonpink etc.), nicht die ungenauste. Der LATeX-Befehl \color{aqua} (oder \color{pink}) wird ja eine ganz bestimmte Farbe mit einen festen RGB-Wert hervorrufen -- warum zeigst du uns nicht einfach diese Farbe und fragst, wie wir die nennen?

Answer (score 3):

Den allgemeinen Farbeindruck des gesamten Bildes würde ich im Deutschen als "Rosa" bezeichnen. Natürlich hat es mehrere Farben.

"Pink" als Lehnwort aus dem Englischen ist im Deutschen inzwischen auch  populär, das würden vielleicht auch manche sagen.

Comment: "Pink" bezeichnet im Englischen offenbar (sagt zumindest meine muttersprachliche Frau) alles was im Deutschen Rosa ist. Im Deutschen ist "pink" m. E. allerdings nur das leuchtende, helle, Rosa, das man z. B. mit Barbiepuppen assoziiert (im Originalpost die Farbe im Rechteck oben links).

Comment: @Raketenolli: Genau, ich kenne "pink" im Deutschen nur als das, was auf Englisch eher "magenta" oder "fuchsia" heißt. (Das deutsche Wort "Magentarot" begegnete mir erstmals im Kunstunterricht der weiterführenden Schule.)